ImportError: cannot import name '' from '' (unknown location)
This is my folder structure
folder structure
I want to import formatting into my jupyter notebook, main.ipynb.I have tried from src.processing import formatting
However, when I try the import, I get ImportError:cannot import name 'formatting' from 'src.processing'
The most frustrating part is that in another project, where I used the EXACT same folder structure, the imports were working in the jupyter notebooks.
from src.processing import encoding

using sys.path.insert


src is in the directory above where your notebook is in the directory hierarchy. This should be closed as a duplicate of here or here
. Did you try from ..src.processing import formatting? Also please don't use images to paste in text. We could more easily look at that if it was provided here in fenced formatted code blocks. See where it boldly emphasizes not to include images of text in 'How do I ask a good question?'.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Since src is only accessible from the directory above notebooks you'll want to try importing the processing directory with .. like so:
from ..src.processing import formatting

This is as per the Python docs here
